# Handling Strings with octal ASCII code (in Java)

Tags: java, ascii

i'm having some trouble with a text file that contains strings like these:
    Grandchamp-le-Ch\303\242teau

It's the name of a Wikipedia page by the way. The two asciis represent "â" I think.

Is there any piece of software that easily converts the string above into 
    Grandchamp-le-Château
or maybe
    Grandchamp-le-Ch%C3%A2teau

I would prefer a java absed solution, but any other idea is just as well!
Any advice or hint is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly hacky way to achieve your goal:

```
final String name = "Grandchamp-le-Ch\\303\\242teau";
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\(\\d{3})").matcher(name);
final StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(out, String.valueOf((char)parseInt(m.group(1), 8)));
m.appendTail(out);
final String decoded = new String(out.toString().getBytes(ISO_8859_1), UTF_8);
System.out.println(decoded);
```

How it works:

1. the regular expression matches the octal character notation;
2. the original string is transformed by replacing each such octal notation with a char whose numeric value equals that octal number;
3. the new string (now in "mojibake" state) is written out as bytes, using a single-byte encoding (any will do, but ISO_8859_1 happens to be the standard one);
4. the bytes are re-read, now assuming they are an UTF-8-encoded string.

The code will print out

```
Grandchamp-le-Château
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are:

```
String myString = "Grandchamp-le-Ch\303\242teau";
byte[] byteArray = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String result = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);
```

This prints:

```
Grandchamp-le-Château
```

Comment: You are relying on Java compiler to parse your octal chars. The string produced *will not* contain the octal notation. Try writing your string into a file and reading it.

Comment: This prints what you want because Java compiler did the replacement for you. To experiment with OP's string, use two slashes in a compiled program.